# how do i resolve oracle 12c tnsping - 03505 error

Tags: oracle

When I ran $tnsping command in oracle 12c enterprise edition, it is giving error which states-

> tns -03505(failure to resolve name.

Below is my tnsnames file details.

> tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\maxon\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome\network\admin\tnsnames.ora Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

[the error message is it desplaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clg2g.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a defined alias that you have in your tnsnames.ora file, which needs to be located in whatever folder the Oracle documentation for your flavor OS is expecting it (in the Unix world, that's typically `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`, `$HOME`, `/etc`, `/var/opt/oracle`), *or* some other directory pointed to by your `$TNS_ADMIN` environment variable. For Windows, define a user or system environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` to point to the folder where you have the file. Also, you pinged 'nacit', but you don't show any alias defined for it. You'll need to add it to the tnsnames.ora file with the appropriate TNS string. If you don't know what that should be, contact your DBA.